# program loading/execution

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, llvm, elf

I'm a beginner in compilers but I'm very interested in learning about how a program is structured (the binary) and how it is read and loaded in memory for execution. What ebooks/books/tutorials do you guys suggest me reading for a quick start?

Comment: My answer contains a lot of relevant links. But it also depends upon what do you understand about programming in general, and about current computer technology.

Comment: Indeed your answer was more what I was expecting, thanks. Could you please suggest more links - preferable for books/tutorials?

Comment: Here are some more informative links: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/info-sources.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compilers and executable binaries are remotely related. (the actual executable is built by the linker `ld`, not the compiler).

On Linux systems, the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) use [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and [demand-paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) techniques to lazily load the program pages, for [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executables. Shared libraries may be [dynamically loaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) and preferably contain [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

You could be interested in reading about [compiler construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book%3aCompiler_construction), Levine's book on [linkers & loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/), the [Linux Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/), the [Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), the [ldd(1)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), [intro(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/intro.2.html), [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [dlopen(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [elf(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/elf.5.html), [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/elf.5.html), [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) man pages.

Try also to understand what `cat /proc/self/maps` is showing you (the memory map of the process doing that `cat`). You can also play with `objdump`.

Answer (score 6):

### ELF File Layout

> **An ELF file has two views:**
>
> - The *program header* shows the segments used at run-time
> - The *section header* lists the set of sections of the binary
>
> Each ELF file is made up of one ELF header, followed by file data.
>
> **The file data can include:**
>
> - *Program header table*, describing zero or more segments
> - *Section header table*, describing zero or more sections
> - *Data* referred to by entries in the program header table or section header table
>
> *The segments contain information that is necessary for runtime execution of the file, while sections contain important data for
> linking and relocation. Any byte in the entire file can be owned by at
> most one section, and there can be orphan bytes which are not owned by
> any section.*

[image]

### Loading a program to memory

> In computing, a loader is the part of an operating system that is
> responsible for loading programs.
>
> It is one of the essential stages in
> the process of starting a program, as it places programs into memory
> and prepares them for execution.
>
> ***Loading a program involves :***
>
> - reading the contents of executable file, the file containing the program text,
>   into memory
> - carrying out other required preparatory tasks to
>   prepare the executable for running.
>
> Once loading is complete, the
> operating system starts the program by passing control to the loaded
> program code.

### The *NIX way

> In Unix, the loader is the handler for the system call `execve()`.
>
> ***The Unix loader's tasks include:***
>
> - *validation* (permissions, memory requirements etc.)
> - *copying the program image* from the disk into main *memory*
> - *copying* the command-line *arguments on the stack*
> - *initializing registers* (e.g., the stack pointer)
> - *jumping to the program entry point (`_start`)*

Comment: Is the loader a library? In an ELF file there are many sections, they are used for program loading, right? What is the relation between these sections and the loader?

Comment: What do I need to write my own loader?

Comment: @JohnTortugo Loader is actually a program, (usually) permanently resident in memory, which handles executables (reads/validate a file according to its format, copying it to memory, and eventually "starting" it)

Comment: @JohnTortugo Why would you possibly want to do such a thing? (I've written a tiny micro-kernel YEARS ago; I've lost the code since... :/ And yep, it did have a loader, as well..) Honestly, other than as a hobby, this thing is really complicated...

Comment: @JohnTortugo Well, if you really want to get your hands dirty (I admit that kernels/compilers/frameworks (ok, maybe put Chess engines in too... lol) are my coding holy grail, and one of the reasons I love programming), try searching google for basic... and I mean BASIC micro-kernels' sources (even linux 0.0.1 source - you may find it someplace - is TOO complicated)... ;-)

Comment: @JohnTortugo A very very basic intro : http://www.scribd.com/doc/2187324/Writing-a-Kernel-in-C

Comment: perhaps he wishes to write a better [disassembler](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) !

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon thanks for you answer and link. I read James Molloy tutorials and found they great! http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/index.html

Comment: @JohnTortugo Yep, I know this one too; just make sure you have some old pc (with a floppy; trust me, it'll make things much easier :-)) to play with... And, yes... kernels (as in-practical as it may seem) is one of the most fascinating things to play with in programming. (I wrote mine - nothing great, could load apps into memory though, and read disk of course; some 10,000 lines of code - some 3-4 years after I read about Mr.Linus... it was 1997? 1998? God bless him! :-)