# (C++11) What's the difference between static array and dynamic array with list initialized?

Tags: arrays, c++11, memory-management, memory-segmentation

For instance, there is an int array with thousands of elements:

```
static int st_indices[9999] = {
   0,  27,  26,    1,  41,  71,    0,  26, 101,    0, 101, 131,    0, 131,  72,
   1,  71, 176,    2,  56, 206,    3, 116, 236,    4, 146, 266,    5, 161, 296,
......
};
```

and

```
int* dy_indices = new int[9999] {
   0,  27,  26,    1,  41,  71,    0,  26, 101,    0, 101, 131,    0, 131,  72,
   1,  71, 176,    2,  56, 206,    3, 116, 236,    4, 146, 266,    5, 161, 296,
......
};
```

What's the difference between above two ways, **especially the values in curly braces on memory usage?**

I know that st_indices will life in memory until the program ends(STACK), and dy_indices will be release after `delete []`(HEAP). or it's a question about stack vs. .DATA segment?

Answer (score 0):

Static are done at compile time..(set amount of memory, aka STACK)

Dynamic are done at run time (dynamic allocation, can be any size depending on system limits, aka HEAP)

Answer (score 0):

From [@Dr.Kameleon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098232/790198) , I learned that **OS will reading the contents of executable file, and loading it into memory.**

That is the data in curly braces will be loaded into the .TEXT segment of memory. If we don't  take virtual memory/paging into account, putting the data in a file then read in, will reduce the memory usage(for an OpenGL app).